# Error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*(*) [4]'[-fpermisive] C++

Tags: c++

Debo hacer una matriz de 4x4, luego cargar la diagonal principal con ceros y mostrarla, para que por último contar en ella los múltiplos de 5.
Quiero enviar la matriz por **referencia**, para poder modificar la original desde la función diagonalpp.
Es importante destacar que **no** tengo permitido declarar **variables globales**.
Me arroja este error y he intentado muchas cosas y no puedo solucioinarlo.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


void diagonalPP (int* m[][4]);
int multiplos (int* m[][4]);

int main()
{
    int f,c,mul, m[4][4];

    for (f=0;f<4;f++) 
    {
        for (c=0;c<4;c++) 
        {
            scanf("%d",& m[f][c]);

        }       
    }
    for (f=0;f<4;f++) 
    {
        for (c=0;c<4;c++) 
        {
            printf("%d", m[f][c]);
            printf("\t");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    diagonalPP (m[4][4]);

        for (f=0;f<4;f++) 
    {
            for (c=0;c<4;c++) 
            {
                printf("%d", m[f][c]);
                printf("\t");
            }

            printf("\n");
    }

    mul= multiplos (m);

        printf("La cantidad de multiplos de 5 es:%d",mul);

}

void diagonalPP (int* m[][4])
{
    for (int f=0;f<4;f++) 
    {
        for (int c=0;c<4;c++) 
        {
            if (f==c)
            {
                *m[f][c]=0;
            }
        }
    }
}

int multiplos (int* m[][4])
{
    int cont=0;
    for (int f=0;f<4;f++) 
    {
        for (int c=0;c<4;c++) 
        {
            if (m[f][c]%5==0)
            {
                cont ++;
            }
        }
    }   
    return cont;


}
```

Comment: Paula tu corrección de 
`void diagonalPP (int (&m)[4][4]);
int multiplos (int (&m)[4][4]);`
me ha sido muy util. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es correcto el parametro que pones al llamar al método diagonal. Con lo que pones solo pasas un valor, y quieres pasar toda la matriz. Pasa simplemente m, que ya se pasa por referencia. Tampoco es correcta la definición del método diagonal ni del método multiplos. También he hecho una corrección en el método multiplos, para evitar que te diga que el 0 es múltiplo de 5.
Te pongo aquí el código resultante

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void diagonalPP (int m[4][4]); 
    int multiplos (int m[4][4]);
    int main() { int f,c,mul, m[4][4];
    for (f=0;f<4;f++) 
    {
        for (c=0;c<4;c++) 
        {
            scanf("%d",& m[f][c]);

        }       
    }
    for (f=0;f<4;f++) 
    {
        for (c=0;c<4;c++) 
        {
            printf("%d", m[f][c]);
            printf("\t");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    diagonalPP (m);

        for (f=0;f<4;f++) 
    {
            for (c=0;c<4;c++) 
            {
                printf("%d", m[f][c]);
                printf("\t");
            }

            printf("\n");
    }

    mul= multiplos (m);

        printf("La cantidad de multiplos de 5 es:%d",mul);
    }
 void diagonalPP (int m[4][4]) { 
  for (int f=0;f<4;f++) { 
      for (int c=0;c<4;c++) 
        { 
          if (f==c) { m[f][c]=0; } 
        } 
  }
 }
 int multiplos (int m[4][4]) 
 { 
   int cont=0; 
   for (int f=0;f<4;f++) 
   { 
     for (int c=0;c<4;c++) 
     {
       if ((m[f][c]!=0) && (m[f][c]%5==0)) 
       { cont ++; }
     } 
   }
   return cont;
 }
```

Comment: Ciri ahora si, el programa se ha ejecutado perfectamente. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, si la respuesta es correcta, ¿puedes aceptarla?. Gracias

Comment: "*Pasa simplemente m, que ya se pasa por referencia*", eso es incorrecto y engañoso. Pasar `m` a una función (siendo `m` una matriz bidimensional `int m[4][4]` **NO pasa una REFERENCIA**, pasa una **copia** de **puntero**, para ser exactos pasa por copia un puntero a una formación de 4 enteros.

Answer (score 1):

> Quiero enviar la matriz por referencia

Pues lo has estado haciendo mal, ésto:

```
void diagonalPP (int* m[][4]);
int multiplos (int* m[][4]);
```

No pasa las matrices por referencia, lo que estás buscando es ésto:

```
void diagonalPP (int (&m)[4][4]);
int multiplos (int (&m)[4][4]);
```

Si la sintáxis te parece confusa, no te preocupes, no estás solo. Por suerte puedes usar un alias para hacer las cosas más fáciles:

```
using m4x4 = int[4][4];
```

El tipo `m4x4` es una matriz de cuatro por cuatro enteros, así que para pasar una referencia a ese tipo de matriz, es tan fácil como:

```
void diagonalPP (m4x4 &m);
int multiplos (m4x4 &m);
```